# Android studio's file explorer has changed

Tags: android, android-studio, project, hierarchy

I just opened Android Studio and I noticed that the project explorer ( hierarchy viewer ) has changed and the project doesn't compile any more because the files are not in their proper location.

here's what the project viewer should be :

[image: before]

and now it's like this:

[image: after]

I can notice also that Android logo has disappeared from the viewer :

[image: android]

And I also get this error message:

[image: error]

Why is this happening ? What is the problem ?

Comment: Click `Enable Android Support` in that last popup ?

Comment: it worked :) Can you post the answer so i can mark it? ( i'm banned )

Comment: Okay.. If you want to get out of a question ban, please **do post some good and useful answers :-)**  ― It's not hard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click on `Enable Android Support`, and your problem should be gone:

[image: Screenshot]

This should fix your problem.